# How to calculate sum of a column using sql

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

```
SELECT 
    [si].[total] AS [netamount],
    *, 
    IIF([invoicedate] >= '01-07-2017', 1, 0) AS [IsGstBill],
    [p].[languagename] AS [arabicname],
    [si].[tax] AS [stax], [si].[Total] AS [NetAmount]
FROM 
    [sales] [s], [accounthead] [a],
    [salesitem] [si], [product] [p]
WHERE 
    [s].[customerid] = [a].[id]
    AND [a].[entrytype] = 'C'
    AND [si].[salesid] = [s].[id]
    AND [si].[productid] = [p].[id]
    AND [s].[invoicedate] >= '01-01-2018'
    AND [s].[invoicedate] <= '30-01-2018'
    AND [CategoryID] = 1025;
```

I wrote this query for get a total amount for selected categories in my sales table.

Like ..,

Category Name : Biscuits

you see this image on my problem , actually **2760** is appeared on top but i have received 2300 .. Actually my query is represents the first row value only. 
How to i populate this particular sum of the amount.

Actually i try  sum() method on my query.  But it's populate total amount for the all bills.

what i am do now to get my output, please guide me.

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Comment: uhmmm....what?...can you explain your problem a little more?, what results are you getting and what results you want to get?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that your comment didn't make the question any more clear for me

Comment: Actually i need to create a sales book on my project and i am group my products at category wise. Like  biscuits , oils, chocolates and so on. Now i am add a search option to search category wise search on my sales book.

Comment: At category wise search on my sales book. first my report show the overall details on my report. in category wise search i show the selected category products total on this net amount. I attach the image on my question,

Comment: Actually the 2760 is displayed under on the net amount column. but i getting 2300 only how to get this particular amount on my report.

Comment: Actually, you are leaving us clueless. Credits to the person solving this bases on info thusfar.

Comment: How have you got the 2760 underneath? Presumably through Running Total fields within Crystal? If so, why not just re-use this in the required location? As an aside, [the join syntax you are using was replaced over 25 years ago in ANSI 92](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You seem to need need some help with figuring out a query. Well you have come to the right place. There are plenty of people around here who want to help. However, you have not provided any of us with enough information so we can help. You see we can't read your mind and have no idea what your tables, data or desired output is. All is not lost though, you can view this link which provides some great insight in how to solve this problem. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use SUM(), you need a group by, maybe like this?

```
SELECT SUM ([si].[total]) AS [netamount],
   InvoiceNO -- not sure about your column name here, pls edit.
FROM [sales] [s]
   , [accounthead] [a]
   , [salesitem] [si]
   , [product] [p]
WHERE [s].[customerid] = [a].[id]
  AND [a].[entrytype] = 'C'
  AND [si].[salesid] = [s].[id]
  AND [si].[productid] = [p].[id]
  AND [s].[invoicedate] >= '01-01-2018'
  AND [s].[invoicedate] <= '30-01-2018'
  AND [CategoryID] = 1025
GROUP BY InvoiceNr -- Same here
```

Comment: Given the available info, it's a start maybe, probably not an end product.  :))

Comment: @vinayakvk Comments like "not helped me" are not helpful to your reader. Ultimately you have a report presentation issue - but I've yet to see how you are "writing" your report.  In addition, you clutter your question with additional issues making it difficult to have an effective conversation about the first issue you posted. As posted, your query isn't the problem - the design of your report is. And until you define what tool you are using to design the report, the comments you receive will be mostly guesses and not particularly useful.